# ModelState.IsValid to save form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Am trying to fix a submit button. Am very new to MVC.

The problem is from an existing save button i have tried copy the code to implement to a new save button.

this is my .cs code

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Save(Roles roleForm)
        {
            try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var role = Srvctx.Roles.FirstOrDefault(w => w.RoleID == roleForm.RoleId);
                role.RoleDescription = roleForm.RoleDescription;
                Srvctx.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
        }
```

The main problem is :

```
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

Shows as false, but it suppose to show something rather than nothing!!

At the moment when i click save it just goes to RoleManagement but doesnt go through the changes if i made any.

any idea where am going wrong.

Thanks

my role class

```
   public class Roles
{
    [DisplayName("Role ID")]
    [Required]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Role Description")]
    [Required]
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer Blacklist")]
    [Required]
    public List<M2DAL.M2Service.vw_RoleCustomerBlacklist> CustomerBlacklist { get; set; }

    private readonly M2ServiceDataContext _m2Sctx = new M2ServiceDataContext();
    public List<M2DAL.M2Service.Role> AllRoleIDs { get; set; }

    public Roles()
    {
    }

    public Roles(int roleId)
    {

        RoleId = roleId;
        RoleDescription = _m2Sctx.Roles.Where(s => s.RoleID == RoleId).Select(c=>c.RoleName).FirstOrDefault();
        CustomerBlacklist = _m2Sctx.vw_RoleCustomerBlacklists.ToList();


    }

}
```

Comment: if its `false`, then the line `return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");` is being hit? have you stepped through to check which property is invalid?  The `ModelState` will have a collection, and you'll be able to check which properties are invalid.

Comment: yeah it retuens to RedirectToAction("RoleManagement"); . iv stepped through it, it only says isReadOnly = false IsValid = false.. has 3 values, but still it doesnt go in it which i expect it to do

Comment: is `Roles` your class or `Security` class? if it's your class, can you post the code?

Comment: iv updated the code with my role class (model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ModelState` is `false` then you have validation errors so you need to return the view so the user can correct those errors, not redirect.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  // save changes and redirect
}
return View(roleForm);
```

I assume your view includes `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` helpers to display those errors. Your catch statement should also not be redirecting to `RoleManagement` because this does not give any indication that an error as occurred. Consider throwing an exception displays an error page or adding an error message to `ModelState` and returning the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are redirecting, hence rendering a new page. If you have a validation error you want to render the same page again with the wrong data (you'll see all validation errors then).

Replace  `return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");` with

```
return View("RoleManagement", roleForm);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the structure of your site. Replace "RoleManagement" with the page tyou are using to edit data.

Comment: right i no what you mean now, and it works! it changes the data, but would you have any idea why it doesnt refresh wheen i use return RedirectToAction. but it shows its changed in the database but not in the browser